# I have "read only" access to my Macintosh HD

Tags: mount, mac, disk, hfs+

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on my Macbook pro.

I need help getting write access to my Mac HD from Ubuntu. I can view and open the files in my Mac HD but I cannot write to the Mac HD. The options for "New folder" or "paste" are just grayed out when I'm in the Mac HD.

I have already gone into OS X and disabled journaling but no luck.

**EDIT 1: A full history;**

When I first installed Ubuntu, I couldn't get ANY access to my Mac HD although I could see it on my "Files" application. I looked up some online solutions and tried this;

1. `sudo apt-get install hfsprogs` (install hfs programs into linux)
2. `sudo mount -o force /dev/sdX /your/mount/point` (not sure what this is)
3. `sudo mount -o remount,rw,force /mount/point` (remount )

...this didnt help.

**what worked for me was;**

1. `sudo useradd -d /home/tempuser -m -s /bin/bash -G admin tempuser` (create a temp user on Linux)
2. `sudo passwd tempuser` (setup passwor for new user)

Reboot and log in as tempuser. Then, open up the Terminal and type in the following commands;

3. `sudo usermod --uid 502 myusername`( match my Ubuntu UID with that of OS X )
4. `sudo chown -R 502:myusername /home/myusername`(no idea what this does)

....but after all this, although I could now access the Mac HD, it remains read only access until now.

Comment: You might want to test this command `sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point`

Comment: I have just tried that I got "mount: /dev/sda2 not mounted or bad option

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so."

Comment: Never never never do a command in `terminal`, especially if it starts with `sudo`, unless you know **exactly** what it does **first**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird but I think I will now answer my own question!...for those who might have the same problem in future.

After messing around trying to implement heynnema's solution, I noticed that my mount options in "Disks" were set to "ro". Even my basic computer knowledge could recognise that meant read only, so(after a bit more research), I deleted the "ro" and bobs your uncle, I now have full access to my Mac HD.

All that was needed was to remove "**ro**" from "**nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,ro,x-udisks-auth**" in the mount options of my Mac partition. I think this is what you might have been suggesting **Arduino**.

Thanks to ever so much to all of you that responded...Now I just need to find out how to add shortcuts to the contents of my Mac disk onto my Ubuntu desktop!

Comment: Oh! You meant r/w access to your "Mac HD" **partition** from Ubuntu. The way your question reads I took "Mac HD" to mean **disk**. I thought that your Ubuntu root was r/o.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Super User](https://superuser.com/q/84446/152045)

Disabling journaling from HFS+ is supported until OS X Yosemite 10.10

install hfsprogs `sudo apt-get install hfsprogs`

then mount `sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdx# /media/mntpoint` or remount `sudo mount -t hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /dev/sdx# /mount/point`

To fix  improperly unmounted:

`sudo fsck.hfsplus /dev/sdx#`

EDIT:

After seeing the updated question,you should do:

`sudo chmod -R +rw myusername /home/myusername`

Comment: I had already done the hfsprogs thing to get access to the Mac HD, I retried when you asked me but nothing new....I also just tried "fsck" and I got ** /dev/sda2
** Checking HFS Plus volume.
** Checking Extents Overflow file.
** Checking Catalog file.
** Checking multi-linked files.
** Checking Catalog hierarchy.
** Checking Extended Attributes file.
** Checking volume bitmap.
** Checking volume information.
** The volume Macintosh HD appears to be OK.

Comment: @Francispart2, please add the steps you have taken to your post so those don't get re-suggested to you.

Comment: do as George suggested,add to your questions what you have done already and the output

Comment: Ok I have edited my question and I have added the full history of my exploits.

Comment: from the setups you have shown,then give permission to write access like `sudo chmod -R +rw myusername /home/myusername`

Answer (score 1):

Your hard disk may have a problem, and then gets placed into read-only mode.

Lets first check the file system for errors...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery Mode
- choose root access
- type `sudo fsck -f /`
- run fsck more than once if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Then lets check the disk hardware...

- start the `Disks` app from the Unity dash
- select the target disk in the left pane
- click on the "hamburger" icon located at the top-right of the Disks window
- select `SMART Data & Tests`
- review the data, run the tests